# How to move TurtleBot in gazebo 7

Tags: microcontroller, gazebo, turtlebot, xml, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to simulate at TurtleBot in Gazebo 7 (with Kinetic Kame), however I am having sending a velocity to the simulated robot. I was able to fix the xacro files to properly create a URDF that Kinetic Kame liked, and  I am also able to receive the Kinect data. However, I am unable to send velocity commands from the nodelet to Gazebo.

Looking into the Gazebo 7 documentation, I noticed that I am expected to use `ros_control` controllers to received data in Gazebo. However, I could not find where in the URDF the existing Indigo implementation of the controllers was. I tried looking in the Koubki configuration file, but all I saw was link and joint information.

Are controllers used in Indigo? If so, where can I find them to modify them? Am I approaching this wrong? If so, how should I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235415/how-to-move-turtlebot-in-gazebo-7/) by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to resolve this myself but noticed that they are working on it on the issue :) ["Will turtlebot be released & supported on Kinetic? #219"](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues/219).

---

Originally posted by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) with karma: 136 on 2016-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0